# String concatenate is not working in Android Linear layout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, string-concatenation

I need to concatenate two string and display with single text view. That string concatenate is working fine within Relative Layout. But i want to concatenate within Linear layout.

Here my code:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
    android:id="@+id/ll"
    android:orientation="vertical"
>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hubraum"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp" 
        android:text="Hubraum :"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="12dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="left"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

.java

```
String title  = "Hubraum: ";
String value  = bikeItemList.getHubraum();
String result = title + value;          
txtCapacity.setText(result);
```

I tried the above type and following type also

```
txtCapacity.setText("Hubraum: " +","+ bikeItemList.getHubraum());
```

But it only display `bikeItemList.getHubraum()`. the "Hubraum:" is not display.

I tried with using append also but it display `bikeItemList.getHubraum()` this text only.

Any one can know the reason.

Comment: what is bikeItemList? Is it List? getHubraum returns what type? Please specify this things

Comment: yes, bike item list is an ArrayList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following way,

```
String str = "Hubraum: " +","+ bikeItemList.getHubraum().toString();
txtCapacity.setText(str);
```

Comment: where is txtCapacity in your xml ?

Comment: txtCapacity in my java code    txtCapacity = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.hubraum);

Answer (score 1):

`StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(128);`

`b.append(title).append(value);`

`b.toString();`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `StringBuffer` and append the string.
display **`txtCapacity.setText(strbuf.toString());`**

Answer (score 0):

Just use append properties of tectview  for only value bcz title is already you have given in xml

```
    String title="Hubraum: ";
    String value = bikeItemList.getHubraum().toString();
    txtCapacity.append(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if it is called from the UIThread, also you can try

```
txtCapacity.invalidate();
```

to force a refresh/redraw.

There's also a chance that your Java code is not called at all, try change the default text from

```
android:text="Hubraum :"
```

to something else, and see if it's the default text that's being shown.